# Integrating Smart Mastering to DHF project

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am newbie to Smart Mastering, but already stuck in the basic procedure.
I have the latest ML9 and DHF already installed on my laptop,
already created my DHF project via Quickstart UI.

1. To call Smart Mastering APIs from my existing project's writer plugin,
   what should I do in advance?
2. When loading match/merge option files, should I better create as
   independent input flow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by @justdewit, the example DHF project should have what you need.  For an example writer, take a look at https://github.com/marklogic-community/smart-mastering-core/blob/master/examples/dhf-flow/plugins/entities/Organization/harmonize/SmartMaster/writer.sjs.

Answer (score 1):

A great place to start is the [example DHF project](https://github.com/marklogic-community/smart-mastering-core/tree/master/examples/dhf-flow) in the Smart Mastering repo.

In there, you can see that match/merge options are being loaded via custom Gradle tasks. You can see an example options load task [here.](https://github.com/marklogic-community/smart-mastering-core/blob/master/examples/dhf-flow/build.gradle#L190)

An example of a task that runs the mastering step via Gradle can be found [here.](https://github.com/marklogic-community/smart-mastering-core/blob/master/examples/dhf-flow/build.gradle#L256)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I would like to call from writer plugin but, the link is dead.